# Upload mp4 file

Tags: php, upload, mp4

I'm trying to upload a mp4 file with php, and I succeed it, but after that, the file can't be run with VLC, even though it could be run before upload. The error message says that the file can't be opened gives me the path of the file and ends with (Bad File Descriptor).
I've made the following configurations in php.ini file:

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 25M
post_max_size = 25M
```

Here is my code:

```
if ($_FILES["video"]["name"] == "") {
     $error = "No video imported.";
  }
  else {
     if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["video"]["name"])) {
        $error = "The file already exists.";
     }
     else if ($_FILES["video"]["type"] != "video/mp4") {
        $error = "File format not supported.";
     }
     else if ($_FILES["video"]["size"] > 26214400) {
        $error = "Only files <= 25ΜΒ.";
     }
     else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES["video"]["name"]);
     }
  }

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <fieldset>
      <div class="area">
         <label for="path">Select file:</label>
            <input class="upload" type="file" name="video"></input>
            <span><?php echo $error; ?></span><br />
      </div>
   </fieldset>

   <input type="submit" name="insert" value="upload"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Does the video file still work if you download it via FTP or SSH?

Comment: Open  video with text editor check start and end for error messages

Answer (score 2):

You had a syntax error on line 4 & 5. It should be

```
} elseif (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["video"]["name"])) {
```

Not:

```
} else {
     if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["video"]["name"])) {
```

This code has been tested and is working.

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["video"]["name"] == "") {
    $error = "No video imported.";
} elseif (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["video"]["name"])) {
    $error = "The file already exists.";
} elseif ($_FILES["video"]["type"] != "video/mp4") {
    $error = "File format not supported.";
} elseif ($_FILES["video"]["size"] > 26214400) {
    $error = "Only files <= 25??.";
} else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES["video"]["name"]);
}

?>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <fieldset>
      <div class="area">
         <label for="path">Select file:</label>
            <input class="upload" type="file" name="video"></input>
            <span><?php echo $error; ?></span><br />
      </div>
   </fieldset>

   <input type="submit" name="insert" value="upload"></input>
</form>
```